# As an UI designer (not knowing any coding at all), what should I keep in mind while designing an IOS/ Android app?

Tags: android, ios, user-interface, user-experience

While working with developers, we, designer constantly face this issue where we don't know anything about how anything works at the code level. This creates a big gap between what we think and what gets implemented. If we knew whether implementing a particular feature is very time consuming, we could design it in a way where it's more convenient for development at lower cost/time without sacrificing the UX.

**Are there any solutions for this?** We've read google material design guidelines/Apple guidelines but still, find there is a big communication gap between Ui designers & Developers ( IOS/ ANDROID).

Let me know what you guys follow in your environment.

Comment: Just a suggestion: Maybe something like a sprint-model is an advantage for you. You may design a part of the app and then meet together with the developers in a regular cycle. Then you can decide and rate how much time some things would take and how complicated it is to implement. I think it would bring much benefits if you also try to understand some things of the code and also the developers try to understand some things of your designing thoughts.

Comment: This is the gospel for iOS UI: https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/overview/themes/

Answer (score 2):

The LESS custom Views the BETTER!!! Just go with the Native stuff.

- It is much better for the user as stuff are the same through all the apps and it is easier.
- When something is custom it means more code. More code means more time. More code means more bugs. More code means more something that you need to read and manage in the future. Like Winnie the Pooh would say: More is more and less is less. In our case: More code is more headache.
- When something is not custom, it means that you are using the Android API which is evolving. Which means that your app will always be new and it will not get old, because the Android Project updates their code and we as developers need to change the version of the API. If something that looks cool was implemented by us, in 1 year it might not look that cool and the only way to change it is by reimplementing it.
- The same problems arises if we try to reuse code by using some external library on Github. In short term it will work well as we are "reusing code", which in programming is good, but in 3 years, the library will be deprecated and you will have to use something else. At the moment I am deleting such libraries from my project.

So what you can do:

- Learn the good design principles for each platform and try to reuse what is out of the box. Then if you really want something else you should really be aware what is the price of it!
- When you try to evaluate the price, please look where are you working. Yes, everybody wants this amazing design, but are your company really willing to pay for it? Really? What resources it has? If the app has shitty functionality the looks won't matter. If you take too much time of the developers to create custom things it will affect the code. Also custom thins which will be hard to support long term.
- Also developers tend to think that the UI people are in general idiots who just don't understand their needs and tend to whatever they want. Don't be the idiot. Stand your ground if you think you are right, but don't you ever agree on something with the developer and then do something else in the mockups.

Also maybe you can look a little bit through the API yourself. There are a lot of pictures and animations: 
https://developer.android.com/guide

[image]